# What's wrong with dhcpd (isc-dhcp-server) inside LXC container? Why it does nothing?

Tags: lxc, lxd, dhcpd

I tried many times, on various Ubuntu machines: the `dhcpd` executable (installed in `/usr/sbin/dhcpd` via package `isc-dhcp-server`) inside the LXC container seemingly **the only thing it does, when executed from command line, is to exit with exit code 1**.

I want to execute the program manually to get interactive error messages and debug problems in the configuration.

For instance, when executing `$ dhcpd --version` I would expect to have at least version like on host

```
$ dhcpd --version
isc-dhcpd-4.3.5
$
```

Inside the LXC container (but not in VirtualBox) the `dhcpd` always outputs nothing to stdout, regardless of the command line options.

---

edit:

I have compared the output of running `strace dhcpd --version` on both LXC container and the host. There is only one difference, at the very end of the output. On LXC guest:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
write(2, "isc-dhcpd-", 10)              = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(2, "4.3.5", 5)                    = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
futex(0x7f2637e2882c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

While on the host analogous part reads:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
write(2, "isc-dhcpd-", 10isc-dhcpd-)              = 10
write(2, "4.3.5", 54.3.5)                    = 5
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
futex(0x7f95cadac82c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

---

I filled the issue against LXD about this problem, see https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/5378

Answer (score 1):

Try running "strace dhcpd --version" to see if this gives more info.

**Edit:**

```
write(2, "isc-dhcpd-", 10)              = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

This means that the process can't write to STDERR (file descriptor 2).

Congratulations, you have actually hit Ubuntu bug [1641236](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxd/+bug/1641236) or [1667016](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxd/+bug/1667016)
Quoting from [lxc issue 2930](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/2930)

> You do have a few workarounds available though:
>   Using ssh instead of "lxc exec" should work fine (as ssh will allocate
>   its own pts pair) Using "lxc exec" and then running a "script" session
>   should have the same effect as ssh You can turn off the tcpdump
>   apparmor profile by symlinking the profile to /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
>   then reload apparmor in the container (or reboot it).

The last workaround seems to be working for both bugs

```
ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dhcpd /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
```

Comment: Nice insight. Never used `strace` before. I found some differences, and I will update the answer